# Excel calculation bug when editing CountIf formulas for partially fixed range

Tags: excel

I've been working on a large data set and ran into what looks to be a very odd Excel bug.

I have isolated the problem down to a CountIf formula with a partially fixed range that is used to check whether an item is a duplicate in the rage above it e.g. `=COUNTIF(C$7:C17,C17)` / `=COUNTIF(C$7:C18,C18)`  copied down the full data set.

When copied down to a large number of rows (say 10,000) the formulas paste and and calculate fine, it is when you try and do anything else with them that the bug occurs. e.g. if you try and Delete / Clear all / copy and paste values on all the cells, the cell progress bar comes up and moves incredibly slowly for what should be a simple process.

If you use a CountIf for the whole range, clearing the value of the cells is pretty much instant. A SumIf for the same partial range also deletes immediately.

You should be able to replicate this yourself by using `=RANDBETWEEN(0,10000)` for 10k rows, copying and pasting values for the random numbers to isolate them as being the issue and applying the partial range countif vs full range countif, then selecting the partial range cells and hitting delete. Note that the issue still arises if calculation is set to manual.

For reference, I am using Excel 2013 64bit on Windows 7 64 bit.

If anyone is up for confirming the bug or knows about an existing bug and potential solutions, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create a new file (save and exit other Excel files!)
2. To create the data to count, in A2 enter =RANDBETWEEN(0,10000) if you have a slow CPU or RANDBETWEEN(0,20000) if you have a faster CPU
3. Copy A2 down to row A10k or A20k.
4. Copy and paste values for column A
5. In B2, enter =COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2) and copy down
6. Once sheet is fully calculated, select all the CountIf cells in column B and use the Clear All function. This is the stage where Excel seems to freeze for 2 minutes for 10k rows for me (have an i7 processor). If it is instant, then let me know what version of Excel and windows you are using.

Comment: are you actually asking something here? in any case, please report a bug to Microsoft

Comment: Can you be extremely specific in how to reproduce this?  I tried to follow your steps and I cannot reproduce anything that is "bug" note worthy.  Took my cp no time at all to copy all 10k rows

Comment: Aprillion  - I'm trying to identify if this is reproducible by others and if it is, whether there other formulas that can achieve the same thing without creating the issue.

Comment: chancea - I have edited in the specific steps to recreate the issue. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Alright I got my Excel to freeze for 30s~1m following those steps...I used 20k everything

Comment: However I still don't know if it is bug worthy....

Comment: Thanks Chancea - I appreciate you repeating this. It seams to scale badly with more rows as with the 40k rows of my real data it is taking about 10 minutes, whereas a CountIf that looks at the whole range is instant to clear.

Comment: Same as @chancea.  Able to freeze it for 30s-1m with 20k entries. Not sure this is a bug.  If you have 20k rows of data, every `COUNTIF` formula is unique and has to be processed individually because of the partially fixed range.  I suspect that Excel is updating its internal model about which cells are involved in calculations.  e.g., it needs to know that cell A1253 is part of (20000-1253) calculations.  Once the formula is cleared from a cell in column B, it frees up one more reference.  It does this 20k times for up to 20k cells at the bottom.  Seems likely to have N^2 performance.

Comment: Thanks Byron. While I thought something like this would make sense, it seams very odd that pasting the formulas initially takes significantly less time than it does to clear them - that is why it seamed bug like to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Byron suspected the time is taken by Excel updating the dependency trees.

If you switch off the dependency tree maintenance by setting Workbook.ForceFullCalculation to true then clearing the 20000 COUNTIF cells is virtually instantaneous.

Note that using this option makes every calculation a full calculation: every formula becomes volatile and the status bar always shows calculate.

Comment: Thank you Charles - this worked perfectly. I haven't seen this function before, and when googling it, your site has by far the best information! It's something I could imagine would be a useful as a default option to turn on and off in the same way you can with calculation, as opposed to having to do it via VBA. I still find it interesting that Excel redoes dependencies for each cell deletion, even when you delete the entire column.

Comment: ForceFullCalculation is an application level setting (despite being a workbook property): but once you have turned it on unfortunately you cannot turn it off again during the current excel session.

Comment: Glad you informed me of that - I would have gotten confused as to why setting ForceFullCalculation back to false wasn't doing anything!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Following Charles' excellent answer, which forces all formulas in a sheet to be volatile for the session, I thought I would try rebuilding the CountIf with a volatile offset function to define the range, and sure enough it worked. So the formula I used was: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,-ROW(A2)+2,0):A2,A2)`

Whether it is better to have a non volatile function that you need to turn on ForceFullCalculation to alter (delete, past values etc.) vs having a large number of volatile formulas will be up to you.

**Original post:**

OK, so I have been trying a few other formulas to see if I could overcome the issue.

Strangely, using `=SUMIF($A$1:A2,A2,$A$1:A2)/A2` would occasionally work, clearing all the data in column B instantly, but was not consistent and would often freeze like the `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)` formula used in the original post.

I also tried some other formulas, such as `=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:A2*($A$1:A2=A2))/A2` as well as the same configuration using Sum in an array formula but never got an instant clear.

I also tried copying blank cells and posting them over the formula cells, but that still froze for the same 30s - 60s that clearing them did. You could cut and paste and that would be fine, but trying to clear would result in the freeze. Deleting the entire column also did not speed up the process. I also tested Excel in safe mode, to no avail.

Given the lack of success, I am guessing that Byron's comment on Excel updating the internal model after each cell is cleared due to the different ranges for each formula is causing the freeze - though I still don't really get why pasting the formulas in the first instance would take a fraction of the time as clearing / deleting them!

As such, I can only conclude that irrespective of the reason, there does not appear to be a formulaic solution that does not cause the freeze, so I will have to use pivot tables / remove duplicates.

I appreciate everyone who tried to replicate the issue - for whatever it's worth, it looked like 3 of use had the issue and 1 did not.

Answer (score -2):

This is caused by your use of the `RANDBETWEEN` function.  I was unable to replicate your results after I used static data in place of this formula for 1 million rows.

The problem is that when you clear the data from the cells it does not happen for all of the cells at the same time.  Excel has to step through each one and update a few things(Value of the cell, formatting, and formula calculation chain) and if anything in the formula chain has changed then all of the formulas recalculate and upon every recalculation all of the `RANDBETWEEN` values also get updated which causes another calculation of all of the `COUNIF` formulas that are affected.

So, for 20k `RANDBETWEEN` values and 20k `COUNTIF` formulas you get about 6 million calculations and up to 18 million writes to disk(depending on caching) when you try to delete all of those formulas.

So, no this is not a bug it is simply an unintended consequence of using the `RANDBETWEEN` function.

Comment: Mr. Mascaro - One of the steps was to copy and paste values on the RandBetween function.

Comment: Then even with one million rows it happens instantly (or with a second).  As I wrote in my answer, I can't replicate when using that step.  And even if you do that it's still 2 million calculations and potentially 6 million writes to disk.

Comment: Interesting - both chancea and Byron did manage to replicate it. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 1) One of the steps was to remove all the `RANDBETWEEN` formulas and replaced them with static values.  2)Turn formula calculation to manual.  The freeze was still reproducible on my end.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro I believe I did, and I just double checked and re-read it.  But if I missed something obvious then I am sorry but perhaps just let me know what it was.  I don't find the guessing game that fun.

Comment: @chancea, even if you can replicate, the fact that I can't means that it's not a problem with Excel, but something on the user side that is causing the issue.  I ran a unit test with the `timer` function in VBA and to delete the 1 million rows of `COUNTIF` formulas took .8174..... seconds

Comment: Well even assuming that you are correct and that your machine cannot possibly without a doubt reproduce this....that still doesn't mean it isn't a problem with Excel.  The only fact we can draw from that is your machine cannot reproduce the issue...so something must be different on your machine than on ours.  Something other than Excel 2013 x64 because that is my setup as well.

Comment: Actually I am an idiot.  I am using Excel 2010 x64 (see what I mean, can't trust no one)

Comment: @chancea, it really shouldn't matter.  I have VM's and I can test in all versions of Excel later, but I feel that it's down to the individual performance of each PC.  The major bottle neck will be disk I/O activity and how that syncs with the CPU clock.  If you look at the Excel XML spec, every cell change requires a lot of disk writes.

Comment: @Mr Mascaro, thats incorrect: nothing gets written to disk until you save. Internally XL does NOT work with XML.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, have you ever heard of virtual memory?  A lot get written to disk for every operation in Excel.  And Excel creates backups unless you specifically tell it not to and writes the file to disk...  I think your knowledge isn't quite up to date.

Comment: @Mr Mascaro, Virtual memory only gets flushed to disk when there is not enough RAM to hold the current page set: this does not occur with every operation in Excel. Auto backup only occurs every few minutes. Disk activity is not the cause of this slowdown.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, please read [this series](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx).  That simplistic view of virtual memory hasn't been true since Windows 3.1.  All well-written windows applications use a combination of physical and virtual memory all the time.  Not when there is a lack of RAM.

Comment: @Mr. Mascaro: I think you misunderstand your references: assuming a few Gig of RAM try running Excel in a few megabytes of memory and measure the paging activity during a calculation: you won't find that paging occurs to any sort of level that is noticeable. Of course if you have a gigabyte workbook and only 512MB RAM you will have more of a problem: but that's not the case here.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, I'll tell Mark that his explanation needs some work when I see him later this week.